# How do you fetch data ( Polygons / Data Pins ) on zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Is there any way by which I can zoom in or zoom out in Azure Maps and get data of all the polygons and data pins in the current window?

Answer (score 0):

After the map has finished moving you can call `map.layers.getRenderedShapes` function to get all rendered shapes in the current view. You can find documentation on this function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.layermanager?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest#getrenderedshapes-position---point---boundingbox--array-string---layer---expression-

If you zoom the map in close enough into an area in the following sample, it loads a list of all locations that are in view, into a side panel using this function: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Simple%20Store%20Locator This sample is covered in detail in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-create-store-locator